# What should I do when faced with an obsolete comment conversation? Why was my flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags

A few times recently I have been involved in protracted comment conversations, usually resulting in editing significant amounts of information into a question and answer. When this happens, [past experience suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256840/are-flags-for-immediate-problems-or-just-problems#comment837938_256904) that mods don't like to have lots of things flagged, [preferring one custom flag or meta post.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21750261#21750261)

Anyway:

- [I created one custom flag on these comments on these comments and they were all deleted by a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31710000/1768232).

  - Flag reason: Most of these messages are obsolete and are pretty clear in the question now. Can they be cleaned up?
- [Today, I also created one custom flag on these comments and it was declined with no explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31753487/1768232)

  - Most of these comments are about editing in more information that have since been added in. Can they be removed?

This seemed completely internally inconsistent, so I went and found the guidelines: [Flagging obsolete comment conversations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182684/flagging-obsolete-comment-conversations). While, true, I did not leave a comment explaining the flag, my reading of that answer suggests that a single flag was the correct way to go. Then, [@JonClements later told me](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24812019#24812019):

> I/mods can't read every single comment and make decisions

I found this confusing, as it seems to me that that *was* done in the first of those two flags.

Can someone explain this to me? What should I do in the case of obsolete entire conversations?

Comment: You were... talking to the moderator in chat. Why didn't you just tell him which comments were obsolete? Surely this is an excessive amount of overhead for such a small thing.

Comment: @Shog9 I was in the process of trying to tell him when he declined my flag...

Comment: I strongly suspect that "most of" is the reason - if you need to cherry pick - flag each comment. Or say "all comments before/after this are obsolete".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I thought that too, until I checked that except that the first flag also says "most"

Comment: It's not clear to me what the outcome of your first flag was (I can't see deleted comments), but it's possible the moderator just ignored the word "most" and deleted the entire conversation. If that was the right thing to do, it proves you should have left the word "most" out of the flag comment (i.e. the first mod made a lucky guess as to your real intent); if it was the wrong thing to do, it proves the hazard of a mod trying to infer your real meaning. Either way, it proves the reasonableness of a mod taking your comment at face value and not taking action on vague guidance.

Comment: @PeterDuniho In the first flag, the moderator deleted something like 10 out of 13 comments.

Answer (score 6):

Argh, this **is** answered on MSE, I just didn't see it when searching the other day.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207967/200235

> My preference would be:
>
> - Use a custom flag when *all* comments on a post are obsolete.  If all comments can be deleted, you might as well save your flags by only using one. We have a tool to purge all comments in a couple of clicks from the post.
> - Use individual comment flags otherwise.  Individual flags are preferred because they're much easier to process directly from the moderator queue without visiting the post (literally one click each).
>
> If you can *make* all comments on a post obsolete by editing them into the post, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I generally flag most of the relevant comments with the tag 'Other' and an explanation that starts with one of the standard reasons (usually 'Obsolete', but sometimes 'too chatty' or 'not constructive') and an explanation of what's up.

For example, on one question recently (a question from 2010, but one which is still relevant), I gave three flags which were deemed 'helpful':

- Not constructive. This comment is wrong, as the next comment states and the one after that concedes. All three comments should go.
- Obsolete: The previous comment is wrong, as this comment states and the one after it concedes. All three comments should go.
- Obsolete: The comment two before this is wrong, as the next comment states and this comment concedes. All three comments should go.

On another question, also from 2010, I added flags that were deemed helpful:

- Obsolete: the homework tag is mercifully ancient history. In any case, the next comment says "it is not an assignment".
- Obsolete: the previous comment is obsolete because it suggests the homework tag. This comment says "but it isn't homework" which is not needed if the other comment is removed.

On another question, this one from mid-July 2015, I added flags that were deemed helpful:

- Obsolete: thanks duly noted (though they may be partially rescinded after my follow-on comment), but not needed for posterity.
- Obsolete. I've seen it, but it doesn't add anything for the long-term.

These were on comments responding to comments I made and probably deleted after my comments had been acted on.  The response comments did not add anything to the long-term health of the site.

And another question from mid-July 2015:

- Obsolete: the data that was in a comment has been moved to the question where it belongs. This is not needed any more, despite my upvote (which was valid when given).
- Obsolete: should have been added to the question by the OP. I've done that and commented that I shouldn't have needed to. This can now go.

Here again, there was material in the comments that has no business sticking around once the question has been edited into shape.  The first was a comment requesting data for the question.  The second was a 'comment' showing the data.

---

I do sometimes use the simple reasons, but I far more often use 'Other' and an explanation.  (Out of a page with 70 flags, 13 were the simple reasons, and the rest 'other' with an explanation.)  And most of the time, those are deemed helpful.

If a moderator pops up and comments that this sort of annotation isn't helpful, then (a) I'll take heed and stop doing it, and (b) you should too.  Otherwise, I believe this sort of annotation helps the moderator make a decision swiftly.

Comment: Today, I flagged four comments in a 7 comment conversation as "Obsolete" (standard) and got helpful on all four. Of the remaining, two were also obsolete but they were mine and I did not need moderator intervention. I did not get a note saying "just do one flag for the conversation.", which I suppose answers my question.